# How to handle save event for a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the JS file, i have a function to pop up modal dialog:

```
   $(".edit-task").click(function() {
        $("#myModal").modal()(
            {
                backdrop:true,
                keyboard:false,
            });


    });
```

Then the dialog shows with two buttons and an textarea:

```
  <textarea id="form-field-task-content" class="autosize-transition form-control" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 52px; color: black">Test1</textarea>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

I want to get the text between  and then save, so what can i do with the two buttons?

```
$(".btn btn-primary").click(function(){});
```

Comment: where is you `save` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a form.Change button type to "Submit". And use Jquery Ajax to POST your data to Server. And from server side you store data in DB.

Something like this :

```
<form id = "form">
 <textarea id="form-field-task-content" class="autosize-transition form-control" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 52px; color: black">Test1</textarea>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

</form>
```

Now use Jquery to Post your data. Example : [Sample](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/form/form1.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".btn btn-primary").click(function(){

$.ajax({
url: "wherever.php",
data: "data="+$('#form-field-task-content').val(),
success: function(result){
alert("You posted to wherever.php");
 }
});
```

wherever.php

"save" data.